# Change from "DefaultPieDataset" to "DefaultCategoryDataset"

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset(); 
while(rs6.next()){      
    pieDataset.setValue( rs6.getString("Status"),rs6.getDouble(2));                        
}
```

I tried to change from `DefaultPieDataset` to `DefaultCategoryDataset`.

```
DefaultCategoryDataset objdataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
while(rs6.next()){      
    objdataset.setValue( rs6.getString("Status"),rs6.getDouble(2));                        
}
```

But no result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "no result"?

Comment: Did u get the import? it's in `org.jfree.data.category`

Comment: yes i have already the import